# Sur le concept nietzschéen « volonté de puissance »

Tags: expressions-idiomatiques

Ma question est, apparemment, toute simple : si le mot qui connecte les deux noms de cette phrase philosophique est, en allemand, [**zu**](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wille_zur_Macht), et en anglais, [**to**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Will_to_power), qui signifie la même chose, c'est-à-dire un mouvement vers quelque chose, pourquoi la préposition qui les connecte est-elle en français **de**, c'est-à-dire une préposition qui ne fait pas (du tout) partie de la même famille sémantique que **zu** et **to** ?

En bref, donc, pourquoi ce concept n'a-t-il pas été traduit d'une manière similaire : *volonté vers puissance* ?

Comment: I won't (can't) go deep but *"volonté de puissance"* is the only way to translate it, as far as I know. I can't think of another preposition that would be correct, neither *"vers"* nor *"pour"*. I'd say it's always the case in French, while in English you can have *"will to something"* (*"volonté de quelque chose"*), *"lust for something"* (*désir de quelque chose*), *"fear of something"* (*"peur de quelque chose"*). But maybe I'm being to categorical.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

La préposition *de* a beaucoup de sens, et entre autres, elle permet d'indiquer la **destination**, l'**utilisation** de quelque chose.

[Voir le TLF](http://www.cnrtl.fr/lexicographie/de) :

> *De* marque une circonstance qui précise (et parfois conditionne) une modalité d'existence ou d'action. [...]
>    La modalité est une destination habituelle ou occasionnelle d'une pers., d'un animal ou d'une chose (but, fin, usage); *de* signifie ***pour*** et introduit un compl. déterminatif. (C'est moi qui souligne)

« La volonté de puissance » c'est la volonté utilisée dans le but d'atteindre la puissance. Comme une « salle de danse » c'est une salle utilisée dans le but de danser / pour la danse.

Les Francophones comprennent très bien cet emploi de *de*, ceci dit, si le premiers traducteur de Nietzsche avait traduit par « la volonté à la puissance » ça nous aurait peut-être paru bizarre (?) mais on l'aurait compris aussi.

Answer (score 1):

Mon sens approximatif de l'allemand m'a toujours fait interpréter Will zur Macht comme Volonté de Pouvoir. Ça peut sembler un peu trop subtile, mais Puissance est plus abstrait, là où Pouvoir, et zur Macht, indiquent "pouvoir faire quelquechose", plus concrètement.    Comme si on sous-entendais Volonté de Faire... Corrigez-moi s'il y a lieu.